# Importing Excel into SQL2005, issue with currency symbols and text in a number field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, excel

I have a field in my Excel as follows

€250
€240
Free
....

In my SQL2005 Preview this looks as follows
250
240
        (Blank)

So it doesnt like Symbols and Text in this column altho it is going to a varchar column.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: When you say varchar, do you mean you are importing into an existing table? Also, which version of Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the € is stored in your excel file as part of the value of a cell or as formatting.

I was trying to reproduce your problem, and when I entered €250 into a cell, when I later selected the cell to check the value, it was 250 (Excel had decided that I was trying to give the cell a numerical value, formatted as currency)

If that isn't the problem, trying using nchar as your column type rather than varchar. nchar allows a wider range of symbols.